# Segmentation Fault calling SWIG Generated Getter

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault, swig

I am wrapping an internal set of libraries written in C++ using SWIG to provide access to an API in Java and I haven’t run into any issues until now.

I have a struct that is wrapped into a Java proxy class with its associated getters and setters.  The generated code actually does work for some time.  However, after enough calls to the getters in Java a segmentation fault occurs and the JVM to crashes.  I am calling the getters in a for-each loop.  For example:

```
for( NativeProxyClass t : ContainerOfNativeProxyClasses )
{
    if( t.getSomeField() == 1 ) /// Segfault occurs in the native code corresponding with this getter only sometimes.
    {
        /// Do something with t.
    }
}
```

I know this may be vague, but I cannot post the exact code.  Like I said this is a strange issue because it does not always occur after a fixed amount of time, sometimes it takes a few seconds, sometimes it happens instantly.  I don’t believe the object is being deleted because I’ve added print statements to the finalizer\delete function of the proxy class.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: There are probably an infinite number of reasons it could be segfaulting.  My best guess based on the information provided is a thread safety issue.  Can you provide the crash log?

Comment: I can tomorrow.  Im not using threads though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my problem.  I was using SWIG's std_vector implementation.  I returned data in a wrapped std::vector and when the vector went out of scope on the Java side, the garbage collector called the finalize method which ended up deleting the data.  Basically, I made a shallow-copy.  Adding a copy-constructor fixed the issue.